# How do I modify/enrich an Eloquent collection?

Tags: arrays, laravel-5

I'm using eloquent relationships.

When I call `$carcollection = $owner->cars()->get();` I have a collection to work with. So let's say that I have, for this particular owner, retrieved three cars. The collection is a collection of three arrays. Each array describes the car.

This is all working fine.

Now I want to add more attributes to the array, without breaking the collection. The additional attributes will come from a different source, in fact another model (e.g. `servicehistory`)

Either I retrieve the other model and then try `merge()` them, or I try manipulate the arrays within the collection without breaking the collection.

All this activity is taking place in my controller.

Is one way better than another, or is there a totally different approach I could use.... perhaps this logic belongs in the model themselves? Looking for some pointers :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be specific, if you do `$owner->cars()->get();` you have a collection of Car Models, not array.

That have been said, you can totally load another relation on you Car model, using

```
$carcollection = $owner->cars()->with('servicehistory')->get();
$carcollection->first()->servicehistory;
```

Comment: Ah yes, that is true - collection of models not cars. 

So the `...>with('servicehistory')...`works because the relationships are established? The thing is each of the car models in the cars collection has a service history.

Comment: Not sure to understant your question correctly.. You have to define a servicehistory relationship in you Car model. Then use the snippet I gave you to eager load it and access it.

Comment: Of course I used `first` just as a proof of concept, servicehistory will be available on every car.

Comment: Ah, that is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.. I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the transform method of the collection.

```
$cars =  $owner->cars()->get();
$allServiceHistory = $this->getAllService();
$cars->transform(function($car) use($allServiceHistory) {
    // you can do whatever you want here
    $car->someAttribute = $allServiceHistory->find(...):
    // or
    $car->otherAttribute = ServiceHistoryModel::whereCarId($car->getKey())->get();
});
```

And this way, the `$cars` collection will be mutated to whatever you want.

Of course, it would be wiser to lazy load the data instead of falling into an n+1 queries situation.